# tqdm not displaying progress bar in Atom

Tags: python, atom-editor, tqdm

Using the tqdm module in Python on a Mac using Atom.
I am trying to use a progress bar with the tqdm module and am using this code:

```
from tqdm import tqdm
from time import sleep
for i in tqdm(range(10000)):
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

and it only returns`[Finished in 0.121s]`.
I don't know whether this is my fault or an Atom error but don't know how to fix it. When I run this code in IDLE it works fine, it is just Atom that doesn't run it.
Any solves?

EDIT:
I changed the code to

```
from tqdm import tqdm
import time
from time import sleep
for i in tqdm(range(10000)):
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

as it started throwing up the error

```
NameError: name 'time' is not defined
[Finished in 0.12s]
```

and now it just displays noting in the console output, not even the `[Finished in 0.121s]` that it did before.

Comment: Atom does not run code, you're likely using a third-party package to do so. The question is: which one?

Comment: Using Script package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you've already imported sleep from time, instead of

```
time.sleep(0.5)
```

try this instead

```
sleep(0.5)
```

Comment: Thanks, and good tip. But, when I run it, there is still no output.